# Dropdownlist population error from dataset asp .net

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, dataset

I am having trouble in populating dataset in Dropdownlist. I want to show username column from my database table in dropdownlist, but only the last row value is shown. I am stuck, after searching for hours I couldn't find any solution, Every code almost gives me same problem.
Here is what i am trying to do:

```
Dataset ds = new Dataset();
ds = db.search();

            if(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count>0)
{
            DropDownList1.DataSource=ds;
            DropDownList1.DataBind();
}
```

In ASP Markup:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: could you please include the code for your search method and any tsql please?

Answer (score 1):

please set below property of Dropdown list as shown in code at server side. Please replace "Username" and "ID" with retrieve recordset column Name.

```
DropDownList1.DataSource = ds;
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "UserName";
DropDownList1.DataValueField = "ID";
DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Using ds As DataSet = data_readers.data.ExecuteDataSet("LoadSearch", NOTHING)
            If ds.Tables.Count > 0 Then
                If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then

                    DropDownList1.DataSource = New DataView(ds.Tables("myDataset"))
                    DropDownList1.DataBind

                End If
            End If
  End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

your "ASP Markup" is totally empty! Here take a look at my code, it should be a good example for your source page:

You Also need to setup a objectdatasource: I provided that code below the drop down list. Listitem value is just a preference of mine. In your situation your column name would replace TRANS_CD_DESC.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTRANS_CD_DESC" DataSourceID="OBJ_TRANS_CD_DESC" DataValueField="TRANS_CD_DESC"
                            DataTextField="TRANS_CD_DESC" AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server" Text='<%# bind("TRANS_CD_DESC") %>'>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="">-- Select One --</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="OBJ_TRANS_CD_DESC" runat="server" TypeName="project1.dbqry"
                            SelectMethod="gProjectCIS"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
```